# change position of some html on hide some html using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I manipulate css using jquery on case like this :
I have two box in a row, when the first box hidden, I change the width of the second box to full of page.

[image: Two form]

After hide for the first form is active, there is a space left. SO the form looked like weird. like this :
[image]

This my jquery to show /hidden the box .

```
// code to hide the first box
$(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
        $("#kotak_pencarian").hide(); //hide the box
        $('#btn-pencarian').show(); // show button for toggle
        $("#kotak_hasil").removeClass("span9").addClass("span12"); //manipulate width second box
    });

    // code to show the first box
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-pencarian', function() {
        $(this).hide(); // toggle button show 1st box
        $("#kotak_pencarian").show(); // show first box
        $("#kotak_hasil").removeClass("span12").addClass("span9"); //manipulate width of second box
    });
```

I debug it using firebug, my code looked like this before DOM jquery,

```
<div id="kotak_pencarian" class="box span3"> .... bla,bla of first box
<div id="kotak_hasil" class="box span9">... bla bla of second box,
```

but when hfirst box is hidden, the code become :

```
<div id="kotak_pencarian" class="box span3" style="display: none;"> .. first box
<div id="kotak_hasil" class="box span12"> ...second box
```

I think I must manipulate css too on jquery, How can I make it the css to neat ?

Comment: Please create a plunker

Answer (score 1):

Where is your button for toggle?
Maybe your class `span 12` on your `kotak_hasil div` can't work properly because of the button?

Or maybe there is a `margin-left` on your `kotak_hasil div`?

Hope it helps